# VBA - Pulling specific data from QueryTables

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using Excel 2011 on Mac, and I am trying to pull data using a QueryTable, but I am forced to have to import the entire table. I am currently pasting the entire table onto a hidden sheet, then using a formula to pull data from the specific cell. To show you what I mean, Here is a sample:

```
 Sub Yield()

 Dim URL As String
 Dim qt as QueryTable
 Dim hs As Worksheet
 Set hs = Worksheets("Hidden Sheet")
 Set ws = Worksheets ("Managed Equity Portfolios")
 URL = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/spy"
 Sheets("Hidden Sheet").Visible = True

 Set qt = hs.QueryTables.Add( _
      Connections:= "URL;" & URL, _
      Destination:= hs.Range("A1"))
      qt.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells = True
      qt.BackgroundQuery = True
      qt.SaveData = True
      qt.Refresh Background Query:= False
      'I am using the same parameters here as my other code, honestly not
       'sure why a lot of it is on here, but I kept it because it works.


 Worksheets("Hidden Sheet").Visible = False

 End Sub
```

Currently, the information I need is being pasted into the Hidden Sheet in cell B42. I made it so the cell that I want the information ='Hidden Sheet!'B42 but this doesn't seem very efficient. Is there any way I could have just the cell B42 be put into Excel?

I'll be on here to clear up any questions, thank you so much!

Comment: probably not. you are actually downloading the web page, so there is no way to run a query. which information are you trying to pull. your example code has nothing in B42. maybe because you are using a Mac and i am not. there may be a web API available to pull just the required value. sort of like this http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/

Comment: Oh I see, I've checked out that website before but I already have that API set up I was just wondering if I could make it more efficient. Thanks for the info!